# Linking a new third party library to a c++ program while working with eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt, header-files

I recently downloaded a third party library called spline-master from github and the file provides a header file called spline.h. I wanted to use this header file so as to create a spline. I am currently using eclipse oxygen for c/c++. I was pretty new to this and have been stuck on this problem since the last few days. I tried changing so many things to link this file. The file can be seen in my project tree and it's there in the includes but when I write #include"spline.h" it throws me an error telling "there exists no such file or directory". 
  Can anyone please let me know how I can go about this problem? All the applications are of the latest version including Ubuntu. I would have attached a couple of screenshots so that you can have a better idea about the problem I am facing[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mP0G.png)
Thanking you.

Regards, 
Sumanth

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mP0G.png)

Comment: Show your project structure - a screenshot will do. What build system are you using (if any), or what compiler options are you using to compile your program?

Comment: Did you add the folder containing spline's headers to the Includes tab at Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols?

Comment: Yes. I have done a lot of googling regarding this issue and have added them accordingly.

Comment: I am extremely sorry if my problem isn't that clear. I was new to this and was trying to find my way through the software and the language. As to build systems, I have been using Cmake but in this case, I didn't use anything as such. 
https://github.com/ttk592/spline
this was the third party file which I downloaded but unfortunately have no idea how to use it! :/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main ways to include a header file, and you need to know where your spline.h is located in order to know which one you can use.

```
#include "spline.h"
```

Enclosing in quotes will tell the preprocessor that the path you have supplied is relative to the location of the code file you are including the file into. Your compiler can't find the file which means it must be located in a directory different to the code file you are working on.

```
#include <spline.h>
```

This is probably the version you want to use. This version will tell the preprocessor to look for spline.h in any header directories you have defined in your project. Again, it considers the path relative to the header directory.